# Problems with CREATE VIEW

Tags: mysql, database

The question is to create a view called NumberOfCities_v. And then use the view to list

countries that have more than 20 cities in the descending order of number of cities.

This is my create a view statement:

```
CREATE VIEW NumberOfCities_v AS
SELECT
    country.code as "Country Code",
    country.name as Country,    
    count(countrycode) as "Number Of Cities"
FROM
    city,
    country
WHERE
    city.countrycode = country.code
GROUP BY country.code, country.name
HAVING COUNT(countrycode) > 20
ORDER BY COUNT(countrycode) desc;
```

I don't get any records, but I think I've created the view. According to my powerpoint, I should be getting both. Apparently I have some field errors with that statement with I try to select the view with another statement. But When I use the exact statement without the create view, I get the results I need. Can someone explain why that is?

Comment: What is meant by *`I don't get anything`*? View is not created? Or it is not showing up any records?

Comment: I think the view is created but not showing any records. Whereas it should be doing both.

Comment: I don't think it is the `VIEW` issue. Try creating a temp table with the same `select` and see if it copies any records into new tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire sql query:

```
Select * from `NumberOfCities_v`
```

to get all the records generated in view.